# How does UWB enable much higher positioning accuracies than Narrowband

Tags: frequency, radio-frequency

literature and internet articles often only explain UWB’s much higher positioning accuracies with its much higher bandwidth compared to the bandwidth of other narrowband technologies such as WiFi/Bluetooth.
For me the bandwidth is only a very good indicator for how much data can be transmitted over a second but I don’t understand how this could help to determine positionins more accurately. It seems that high bandwidth enables us to make use of ToF whereas ToF isn’t available in narrowband systems. But why is that the case?

In APS006 Part 1 of Decawave docs (I use Decawaves DWM1001 modules for an RTLS) there is this graphic which should explain this situation. Essentially the signal level in narrowband systems rises slower which is subject to higher interference of other signals. I get that but then my question is why does this slow rise only happen in narrowband systems? Is it because UWB makes use of impulse radio (IR) and narrowband makes use of continuous waveforms? But why doesn’t a narrowband system use IR then, too?

[image: Narrowband vs UWB]

Please notice that I am not coming from a radio transmission engineering background so my knowledge isn’t that big in this field.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable answer myself.
The difference between ultra wideband and narrowband communications are their bandwidths. For precise localization purposes it is better to make use of ToF than RSSi for several reasons. For ToF it is necessary to emit very short pulses that last about 2 ns.
So the question is: Why does UWB make use of ToF while WiFi/Bluetooth make use of RSSI?

The answer lies in Heisenberg's uncertainty applied on radio waves. Looking at the uncertainty it becomes clear that bandwidth and pulse width have a realtion with each other. The higher the bandwidth is, the smaller the pulse width can get and vice versa. Since UWB's bandwidth is much larger than WiFi's, pulse widths in UWB can become very short whereas in WiFi they are much larger than UWB's(of course they are still very short but in comparison they are much higher).
This means that WiFi could emit impulses as well but since they last longer they are subject to multipath interfences whereas UWB pulses are so short that the chance of multipath interference is incredibly low.
That's the reason why UWB can make use of pulses and that's the reason why WiFi sticks to RSSI measurements.

Read more about it here: https://www.pozyx.io/technology/how-does-uwb-work

Cheers, Max